# Transparent SVG not transparent in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I have a svg image made by a graphic-designer for me in Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4 which has an area which fades into transparency using the Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter (or at least i guess, i'm not good in reading svg in code). Viewed in Chrome it does what it's supposed to do but it doesn't in Safari, where the area just fades into white instead of transparent. Is there a reason for this? And a possible way around? 
Here is what it should look like:

[image]

And here is what it looks like in Safari:

[image]

Here is my CodeSnippet:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: coral;
}
.window {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://anjakaiser.info/HomeComing/200514-Homecoming-window-03.svg" class="window">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem - it's a problem in the SVG Version. In SVG 1.0 there seems to be a problem with transparency gradients. Once we exported the SVG file in SVG 1.1 it worked like a charm.